# How to save an Illustrator document as PDF in a different paper format?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I have several Illustrator documents in 'A1' paper format that I need to save as PDF in 'A3' format, with in addition disabling editing capabilities. These smaller PDF are typically web versions of the full document.

I don't see any way to change the paper format in the 'Save Adobe PDF' options window. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting/Saving to PDF does not generally mean you want to alter the page size. And really, there's no option to resize when saving/exporting to PDF.

Ideally, you configure the Illustrator file at the desired output size.